# How to mock Identity Platform Authentication to trigger beforeCreateHandler

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, google-cloud-functions, ts-jest, google-cloud-identity

I have a google cloud function which I run in Google Identity Platform in the `beforeCreate` trigger which looks like this:

```
import * as gcipCloudFunctions from "gcip-cloud-functions";
const authClient = new gcipCloudFunctions.Auth();
const beforeCreate = authClient.functions().beforeCreateHandler((user, context) => {
 console.log("Hello world");
 });
export default beforeCreate;
```

How do I go by to create jest test to mock this event? Or How can I create test to execute this function?

[Blocking Functions](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/blocking-functions#:%7E:text=Creating%20a%20blocking%20function,-The%20following%20steps&text=Go%20to%20the%20Identity%20Platform%20Settings%20page%20in%20the%20Cloud%20Console.&text=Select%20the%20Triggers%20tab.,and%20then%20click%20Create%20function).

Comment: Can you please provide some details regarding what you are trying to achieve? This cloud function is just to redirect the authentication pager to blocking functions?

Comment: Yes exactly. I would like to simulate an authentication to call this beforeCreate trigger.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, GCP is not having such a feature as far as I know. However, you can try requesting it as a feature. You can use [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) to request this feature.

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/244483989